# A duplicate question of lower quality with a high-quality answer

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

My [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61918/where-do-bulgarians-originate-from) has been marked as a duplicate. The alternative [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26889/what-were-the-origins-of-the-bulgarian-people) asks the same thing but is very short. Probably that's the reason it was downvoted to the point of closing. But it has a single high-quality answer.

IMHO the two "threads" should be merged *somehow*. I would have edited my question text into the original poster's but:

- my question already has one answer as well
- it wouldn't be a merge, it would be a complete rewrite
- quoted sources are ... `wikipedia` which ... come on!

Now what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clarify a few points:

1. Your question has **not** been marked as a duplicate. Some users have merely suggested it to be one.
2. The other question was not "downvoted into closing" - **downvotes cannot do this.** It was closed because the claim that Hungarians were Turks seems disproven by basic research.

In my opinion, these two questions are not actually duplicates. The other question is focused on the veracity of claims for a Turkish origin for Hungarians and Bulgarians, while yours is a more open question asking about Bulgarian ethnogenesis.

However, there's a good answer on the other question, that also answers your question. It is, I think, a bit of a shame to let it languish on a closed question. Likewise, your question has received a good answer as well, that we wouldn't want to go to waste.

This makes marking these two questions as duplicates an unattracting option, in my view.

I therefore agree that a merge may be the best option. Since the other question has been closed and by all appearances abandoned, while yours demonstrate much greater effort as befitting of History.SE's current standards, I have merged the old question into yours.

My apoplogies for rendering the Hungarian portions of the old answer seemingly off-topic. Nonetheless, I think overall the benefits here outweight the harms.

Comment: Thank you for your service, soldier <bows down>.

Comment: As the not-at-all disinterested author of the answer in question, I think this is a good move. However, it does mean I'm going to have to make some edits to that answer, since half of it talks about Hungarians, while the question it got merged into doesn't care about that at all.